# Filter a collection by a list of a single property on the collection's documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am looking for the most efficient way of filtering a collection of documents that contain a userId property by a list of userIds. I am working c# and mongodb driver. All my other "search" code uses linq with this and that would be my preference (unless there is a good reason to do this some other way).

If I were doing this with SQL (which I feel much more familiar with) I would probably create a temp table and join the two to get a filtered list of documents. I am wondering what the best way of doing this in MongoDB would be.

For example I have a collection of documents that look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("606e33de0f0beadb86ac119b"),
    "UserId" : "c1f0fc60-e0c1-480e-b765-8baae0ecbb4f",
    "First" : "David",
    "Last" : "Example",
    ...
}
```

and I have a list of UserIds that I want filter against.  That list could be anything from a handful to thousands.

Edit: I know how this can be done in general using linq but I know that this doesn't always translate into the most efficient mongodb query.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-8.0 Should help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection named `users` that contains objects that have a `UserId` property, and a `List<UserId>` called `userIds` that you want to filter the collection with, you can do:

```
List<User> filteredUsers = users
    .Where(user => userIds.Contains(user.UserId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I understand that is how you would do it using linq but is that definitely the most efficient way of doing it with the mongodb driver?

Comment: What issues are you seeing? Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: I have not actually tried this method with a large list of user ids but my initial thoughts is that it would generate a mongodb query with a long list of ids in it. I am wondering if that is definitely the most efficient way of doing this. If there are thousands of ids it create a very long query string.